# Arrays names PHP Concatenation

Tags: php, arrays

How can I concatenate arrays in PHP5 without repeating the name?

This is what I tried to do, but it doesn't work:

```
$thisProduct = $data['deliveryMethod'][1209];
$thisProductReceiver = $thisProduct['receiver'];
```

And after I do:

```
$lastName = $thisProductReceiver['lastName'];
```

I get this error:

```
Illegal string offset 'receiver'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you are mixing arrays with normal variables.

See here, the first line

```
$thisProduct = $data['deliveryMethod'][1209];
```

`$thisProduct` is a normal variable, (not an array). You are storing the value from an array `$data` to this `$thisProduct` variable.

Now see the second line
`$thisProductReceiver = thisProduct['receiver'];`

You are assigning `thisProduct['receiver']` to `$thisProductReceiver` variable. The Problem here was we already know that `$thisProduct` is an array but you are accessing it as an array `thisProduct['receiver'];` [Which is the source of the error]

Comment: So there is a way to make the name shorter than is it?.
I don't want to write every time like this : $data['deliveryMethod'][1209]['receiver']['lastName']

Comment: @nabill. Does it work accessing like that? ( `$data['deliveryMethod'][1209]['receiver']['lastName']` ). Because the error tell us that what is inside `$data['deliveryMethod'][1209]` is not an array.